# How can I deploy the Vite application on any URL instance without manually changing the basename?

Tags: iis, vite, basename

I use ViteJS + React in my application, which should be deployable on any instance. The application has deep-routed routers, such as myapp/dev/measurements/1834.

To achieve this flexibility, I set the 'base' parameter in the ViteJS config as './' and the 'base href' in the index.html file of the app build.

```
<base href="/" />
```

This setup works well. When deploying, for example, to the URL myapp/dev.com, I simply set the href as '/dev/'. Alternatively, when deploying to a direct URL address, I keep the href as '/'.

However, I encountered an issue because Vite renders indexes for chunks in each build. While this resolves the client browser caching problem, it requires me to manually change the href each time I deploy.

To address this, I considered moving the 'base href' to a configuration file (config.js). This way, I could update the deploy by overwriting the index.html without affecting config.js. The challenge now is that I don't have information about the correct file path to this config.

Do you have any ideas on how I can configure the basename to avoid manually changing text on each deploy of each instance?

The application is deployed on IIS, so I'm unsure if I can configure server redirects.

Comment: Perhaps you can use an environment variable to specify the base path during the build process. In your Vite configuration, you can access environment variables through process.env. If no environment variable is provided, the root path is used by default. At deployment time, you can set environment variables through build commands or other means.